# PHPMyAdmin of MAMP giving me #2002 mysql error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

So only when I go to my local PhpMyAdmin window, I get the #2002 message.
I searched the net and I found a terminal command to check if Mysql would be running in the first place and it does.

Running `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p`

gives me

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 6
Server version: 5.5.9 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.
```

That doesn't look bad I think so the error must not have much to do with that.

I read that there's the config.inc.php file where you replace the value 'localhost' with '127.0.0.1' but that didn't change the situation.

Then I went looking in MYSQL forums it is suggested to check the my.cnf file to check for certain values. but I can't find it anywhere. Is there another file that has the same function in MAMP?

Comment: did it run ok before or was giving this error after installation? If so, just reinstall the whole thing.

Comment: I actually already uninstalled and reinstalled MAMP and Still giving me the same 2002 error.

Comment: which OS are you using? I would recommend us xampp.

Comment: I'm running Mac OSX. The problem came with drupal sites. Xampp doesn't see my drupal installations for some reason which has been an issue on its own in the past and I solved that using MAMP

Comment: don't know if this http://serbiancafe.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/mamp-error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmpmysqlsock-2/ would be helpful.

Comment: No that page was also one of the first things I found when I started google searching this problem. Didn't work. Besides, the other solution on that page mentions the my.cnf file which is missing

Comment: right you might want to create it. That could be a problem.

Comment: Created the my.cnf file under Applications/MAMP/conf/ and added the content that I got from the mysql form (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?35,64808,254785#msg-254785). Still nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Since the top-voted answer was hosted on Posterous, which no longer exists, this is a bit of an orphan. The content is [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20130326113933/http://alextoul.posterous.com/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-so) at Archive.org but just in case *that* goes away, too, the linked answer was:

> Today, I tried to install Mysql on OS X Lion using [SQL Packager](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). I faced a [very common issue](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=MySQL+Forums+%3a%3a+Install+%3a%3a+ERROR+2002+%28HY000%29%3a+Can%27t+connect+to+local+MySQL+server+through+socket+%27/tmp/mysql.sock%27+%282%29):
>
> *MySQL Forums :: Install :: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)*
>
> Turns out you can regenerate this file in the terminal with this:
>
> `ps -e|grep mysqld`
>
> `sudo mysqld_safe`
>
> Thanks [David Bocage](https://twitter.com/davidbcg) for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Alright,

I finally got my PHPmyadmin page loaded again without getting the #2002 error. What I did is I kept reviewing the settings for the mysql socket file until at a certain point my phpmyadmin did show up the way it should. So I'm still not really sure why it happened.

I also noticed there was a portnumber mismatch between the actual port setting in MAMP (8888) and a certain php file I cant remember (where it was 3306) which set to match again. Can't be certain that this is what made it work though.

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem. Easy fix:**

Go to /Application/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin/ and open up `config.inc.php`

on `line 71` you see `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']`

For some reason the default ports got switched on my machine, so I set it to `8889`. Save and phpmyadmin is back up and working!

Wooo